# Extracting new errors from log file and emailing result

Tags: python, python-2.5

The following python 2.5 script works but as I am a beginner I wonder if there any blatant mistakes or perhaps a better way do what I am trying to achieve?

The aim is to open the current day's log - '/Library/Application Support/Perceptive      Automation/Indigo 5/Logs/' and extract the lines that have the word error and email only the new errors.
After the error lines are extracted the number of lines are counted (`prenumLines`) in `tmp.txt`. The extracted lines are then written to the `tmp.txt` file and the lines
counted again (`postnumLines`).  Line numbers greater  than the `prenumLines` are printed to 'theBody' and emailed.

```
from datetime import date
import linecache

fileDate = str(date.today())

theBody = []

tmpFile = open('/Library/Application Support/Perceptive Automation/Indigo 5/Logs/tmp.txt')

prenumLines = sum(1 for line in tmpFile)

log= open( '/Library/Application Support/Perceptive Automation/Indigo 5/Logs/' + fileDate + ' Events.txt', 'r' )

tmpFile = open('/Library/Application Support/Perceptive Automation/Indigo 5/Logs/tmp.txt', 'w')

for line in log:
    if 'Error' in line: 
    tmpFile.write(line )
log.close()
tmpFile.close() 

postnumLines = sum(1 for line in open('/Library/Application Support/Perceptive Automation/Indigo 5/Logs/tmp.txt'))

lineNum  = prenumLines

while lineNum < postnumLines:
    theBody.append(linecache.getline( '/Library/Application Support/Perceptive Automation/Indigo 5/Logs/tmp.txt', lineNum + 1) )
    lineNum = lineNum + 1
tmpFile.close() 

theBody =  "".join(theBody)  

#theBody is the body of  an email which is sent next
#print theBody
```

Answer (score 0):

There are changes that you, speaking from my experience, really should consider making (I use **must**, but it is still just a recommendation), and some others that are more my personal style (where I use **should**).

On a meta level: Your question was originally only tagged [python-25](/questions/tagged/python-25) which is probably why it did not get any attention, you **must** use [python](/questions/tagged/python) which has many more followers on SO.

You **must** not use TAB and space characters in file. Your source is actually indented incorrectly here on SO because of that. The line:  `tmpFile.write(line)` should be indented one level under the `if` statement above it.

You **must** not use the same string that is a filename four times, replace it with a variable.
And create that variable from the common base directory using `os.path.join()`

You **should** consider following [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) the style guide for Python.

Your program will not run if you would try this the first time around, as 'tmp.txt' does not exist. Fail gracefully with a prenumLines of 0 (however I am not using this at all anymore, see below):

```
try:
    # open the file
    # count the lines
except:
    prenumLines = 0
```

I actually wonder that you state that your code works, as you overwrite `tmp.txt` and only write the Error lines *from the last log* in there. The moment you assign to `tmpFile` again, the first open for reading is closed. You then close the `tmpFile` opened for writing twice (for which Python does not throw an error). If yesterdays log had one error and todays three, your email will only show two lines. To append to a file use open(filename, 'a')

You **should** consider using the [with](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement) statement (new in Python 2.5) when reading/writing files, that way you dispense with (erroneous `.close()` statements).

You **should** consider creating `theBody` as a string and appending the lines. Using a list first and join them might be faster, but this script is only running once a day.

There is no need to count the lines and than append the error lines and then reread them and store them in `theBody`, you **should** dispense with the first and third part and do it all in one go:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import os
from datetime import date

baseDir = '/Library/Application Support/Perceptive Automation/Indigo 5/Logs'
tmpFileName = os.path.join(baseDir, 'tmp.txt')

fileDate = str(date.today())
eventFileName = os.path.join(baseDir, fileDate + ' Events.txt')

theBody = ''

with open(tmpFileName, 'a') as tmpFile:
    with open( eventFileName, 'r' ) as log:
        for line in log:
            if 'Error' in line:
                tmpFile.write(line)
                theBody += line

# theBody is the body of  an email which is sent next
print theBody
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed response. I am currently going through it to try to understand your comments and changes. I don't know if it would change some of your response but what I am trying to do is send theBody as an email but only for any new errors since the previous e-mail.The log containing the errors is named from the current days date an it is only the current log that I want to get the error from. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried your original script with a test of a `tmp.txt` of one Line and 3 lines out of 5 that did in the daily log. The `tmp.txt` did not get appended, but overwritten. Did you not see that behaviour? If there are any questions after going through this just let me know.

Comment: The software that generates the log is Indigo, a automation program. It writes to the a new log daily. I set up the script to parse the log every 10 min and look for errors and email them. I wanted new new errors and not ones previously sent. I counted the lines in tmp.text, and added the new errors, any errors previously written were overwritten. So if there were 5 lines in the tmp.txt and 3 more added it would only send the 3 new lines. I made some of the changes you suggested but I found I cannot use a script containing 'with statements' in the software. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you are running Python2.5, make sure you include the top line of my example ( `from __future__ import with_statement`)

Answer (score 0):

Anthon - Many thanks again for taking the time to respond. The software that generates the log is Perceptive Automation Indigo, a home automation program. It is continually writing to the log with a new log generated daily. I set up the python script to parse the log every 10 minutes and look for errors and then email them to me. The challenge I had was to have only new errors emailed to me and avoid the ones previously sent. How I did this was to count the number of lines in tmp.text, then add the new errors, if any errors had been previously written they would be overwritten as you mention. So if there were 5 lines in the tmp.txt and 3 more added it would only send me only the 3 new lines. I made some of the changes you suggested that being using the with statement which shortened up the script and got rid of the close statements. I also replaced the file names with a variable. After doing this the script ran fine but for reasons in the design of the software I cannot use a script containing 'with statements'. I now have to rewrite the script to remove the with statements. You have been a big help and I thank you kindly.

Comment: Can you not use the with statement even if you include the `from __future__ import with_statement` line? That should work in Python2.5